How to draw a vertical dashed line in Tabular environment?
I want to draw a vertical dashed line in my table but latex seems to ignore both ":" in the code before D{.}{.}{-3}. Why?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{rotating} % For sidewaystable

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{Regression Results}
\label{tab}

\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lD{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} :D{.}{.}{-3} :D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} :D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3}}
\hline
\hline
& \multicolumn{6}{c}{Dependent variable: Y} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Dependent variable: X} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Dependent variable: R} \\
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{TFE} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{CFE} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{YFE} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{RE} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{PO} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{FD} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{TFE} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{CFE} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{YFE} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{RE} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{PO} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{FD} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{TFE} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{CFE} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{YFE} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{RE} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{PO} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{FD} \\
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(7)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(8)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(9)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(10)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(11)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(12)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(13)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(14)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(15)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(16)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(17)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(18)} \\
\hline
X & 0.652^{**} & 0.951^{***} & 0.984^{***} & 1.183^{***} & 0.999^{***} & 0.215^{***} & -0.764 & 1.465^{***} & -0.259 & 1.466^{***} & 0.438 & 0.476 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
& (0.269) & (0.199) & (0.136) & (0.122) & (0.137) & (0.046) & (0.998) & (0.297) & (0.904) & (0.298) & (0.728) & (0.408) &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}


Your MWE having some errors, please post the error free MWE

@MadyYuvi I apologize for that. Just edited the code. Thank you in advance for your help!

Sorry, still having the error for the column type D

Thanks for your feedback. I copy-pasted my code from above and was able to compile without errors on a new template with exactly this code. Then, I don't understand why it doesn't work in your latex version. Thanks anyway!

I believed that, you missed something about dcolumn

@MadyYuvi I added the package dcolumn now but I still don't see any vertical dashed lines in the table.

vertical dashed lines are usually done using the arydshln package, surely any documentation you have seen suggesting : might produce a dashed line must have mentioned that package.

unrelated but don't scale tables with adjustbox, resizebox etc.

@DavidCarlisle Yes, but even wit this package it won't work.

If I try your code, I do get vertical dashed lines (at least in cells where you don't remove the lines with the unnecessary multicolumns)

Can you please add a screenshot of what you get?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Oh, now it is also working for me. I don't know why it was not working before. Thank you!

@TFT ... maybe scaling the table makes it hard to read so you missed the dashed lines? :)

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz :) No, I had copy-pasted the code into my original working document and there it's actually still not working. But it works in a new template if I only copy-paste the code above. I guess some other package is hindering the vertical dashed lines in my working doc. I'll continue looking for the bug. Thanks anyway for your help!

you post an example that does not use the package at all so give syntax errors and just state in comments that if you use the package "it won't work" that is not a useful way to help people answer. Please edit the question to make an example that you think should work and show what error you get if it does not.

You could use tabularray with siunitx, but you're obliged to use adjustbox because (even with \tiny fonts) your table exceeds the page margins.
Why don't you transform it in a horizontal table with three parts (something like the second example of my MWE)?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{rotating} % For sidewaystable

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
\sisetup{
    input-symbols = {()},
    }

\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}[!htbp]
\centering\caption{Regression Results}\label{tab}
\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={l*{18}{S[table-format=1.3]}},
  columns={%font=\tiny,
  leftsep=10pt,rightsep=18pt},
  column{1}={colsep=2pt},
  stretch=0,
  vline{8,14}={dashed}
  }
\hline
\hline
& \SetCell[c=6]{} {{{Dependent variable: Y}}} &&&&&& \SetCell[c=6]{} {{{Dependent variable: X}}} &&&&&& \SetCell[c=6]{} {{{Dependent variable: R}}} \\
& {{{TFE}}} & {{{CFE}}} & {{{YFE}}} & {{{RE}}} & {{{PO}}} & {{{FD}}} & {{{TFE}}} & {{{CFE}}} & {{{YFE}}} & {{{RE}}} & {{{PO}}} & {{{FD}}} & {{{TFE}}} & {{{CFE}}} & {{{YFE}}} & {{{RE}}} & {{{PO}}} & {{{FD}}} \\
& {{{(1)}}} & {{{(2)}}} & {{{(3)}}} & {{{(4)}}} & {{{(5)}}} & {{{(6)}}} & {{{(7)}}} & {{{(8)}}} & {{{(9)}}} & {{{(10)}}} & {{{(11)}}} & {{{(12)}}} & {{{(13)}}} & {{{(14)}}} & {{{(15)}}} & {{{(16)}}} & {{{(17)}}} & {{{(18)}}}\\
\hline
X & 0.652** & 0.951*** & 0.984*** & 1.183*** & 0.999*** & 0.215*** & -0.764 & 1.465*** & -0.259 & 1.466*** & 0.438 & 0.476 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
& (0.269) & (0.199) & (0.136) & (0.122) & (0.137) & (0.046) & (0.998) & (0.297) & (0.904) & (0.298) & (0.728) & (0.408) &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
\hline
\end{tblr}\end{adjustbox}
\end{sidewaystable}


But why don't restyle the table in three parts?
\begin{table}
\centering\caption{Regression Results}\label{tabrestyled}
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={l*{6}{S[table-format=1.3]}},
  columns={
  leftsep=10pt,rightsep=18pt},
  column{1}={colsep=6pt},
  }
\hline\hline
& {{{TFE}}} & {{{CFE}}} & {{{YFE}}} & {{{RE}}} & {{{PO}}} & {{{FD}}}\\\hline\hline
& \SetCell[c=6]{} {{{Dependent variable: Y}}} &&&&& \\
& {{{(1)}}} & {{{(2)}}} & {{{(3)}}} & {{{(4)}}} & {{{(5)}}} & {{{(6)}}}\\\hline
X & 0.652** & 0.951*** & 0.984*** & 1.183*** & 0.999*** & 0.215***\\
& (0.269) & (0.199) & (0.136) & (0.122) & (0.137) & (0.046) \\\hline
& \SetCell[c=6]{} {{{Dependent variable: X}}} &&&&&\\ 
 & {{{(7)}}} & {{{(8)}}} & {{{(9)}}} & {{{(10)}}} & {{{(11)}}}& {{{(12)}}}\\\hline
 X & -0.764 & 1.465*** & -0.259 & 1.466*** & 0.438 & 0.476\\
& (0.998) & (0.297) & (0.904) & (0.298) & (0.728) & (0.408) \\\hline
& \SetCell[c=6]{} {{{Dependent variable: R}}} \\
  & {{{(13)}}} & {{{(14)}}} & {{{(15)}}} & {{{(16)}}} & {{{(17)}}} & {{{(18)}}}\\
\hline
X &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
&  &  &  &  &  &  \\
\hline\hline
\end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}

Your table:

My suggestion:

